# Why getFileSize not being imported

Tags: file, haskell

I am trying following code:

```
 import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents, doesFileExist, getFileSize)

-- ...more code

readALine :: FilePath -> IO ()
readALine fname = do 
  print $ "Filename: " ++ fname
  ff <- openFile fname ReadMode
  if getFileSize ff > 0 then do 
      fline  <- hGetLine ff
      hClose ff
      print $ "First line: " <> fline
  else return ()
```

But getting following error:

```
$ runghc firstline2.hs

firstline2.hs:6:63: error:
    Module ‘System.Directory’ does not export ‘getFileSize’
```

Why this is not getting imported when it exists in [package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.3.2/docs/System-Directory.html#v:getFileSize)?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the `directory-1.3.3.2` package (look at the version of the package). Since `getFileSize` is a `FilePath -> IO Int`, you should first obtain the filesize with `fs <- getFileSize ff; if fs > 0 ...`.

Comment: How do I check package version? I am working on Debian Stable Linux with ghc version: `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.1`

Comment: You can check `cabal list directory` and look what version is listed under `Installed versions:`.

Comment: `Installed versions: 1.2.6.2` while needed is `1.2.7.0` or later. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can I use `fileSize`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.4.2.0/docs/System-IO-HVFS-InstanceHelpers.html#v:fileSize

Comment: @mso: what about `cabal install directory-1.3.3.2`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: @rnso That's a different question. Please don't ask new questions by editing old ones.

Comment: OK. If you enter your comments as an answer, I will accept it.